# White Borders around images

Tags: html, css

Good evening.
I uploaded a test index page and the top image has a hover grey background and the social icons at the bottom, have grey backgrounds and they all have white borders.

Rather confused.

http://www.garyhornephotography.com/str/index.html

*** I cannot see how to create a JS Fiddle, so I have added the css and HTML.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */


#wrap1 { width: 1000px; height: 100px; background-color:#F9C6C7; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top: 1px; }
#wrap1 table { width:1000px; }

.first { float:right; padding-top: 10px;}
.third { float:left; }

#wrap2_wrapper { width: 1000px; height: 250px; background-color:#000000; margin: 0 auto; }
#wrap2_wrapper img { padding-top:1px; border: none; max-height: 100%; margin: 0 auto;}


#wrapperMain { width: 1000px; min-height: 2000px; background-color:#ffffff; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top: ; padding-top: 5px; }
#wrapperMainvideos { width: 1000px; min-height: 1100px; background-color:#ffffff; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; }

#wrapperMain1 { width:1000px; height: 1000px; background-color:#ffffff; }
#wrapperMain2 { width:1000px; height: 250px; background-color:#ffffff; }
#wrapperMain2 p { font-family:open-sans; font-size:14px; color:#000000; font-weight:100; }
#wrapperMain2_subleft2 { width:auto; height: 200; background-color:#F6BE44; }
#wrapperMain2_subright2 { width:auto; height: 200; background-color:#F6BE22; }

#wrapnews2 #wrapnews3 {border-bottom: 3px solid #4588ba; margin-bottom:10px;}

#wrapnews2 { width:1000px; height:810px; background-color:#ffffff; margin: 0 auto;  }
.wrapperMain2news { width: 1000px; height:810px; background-color:#ffffff; margin: 0 auto; }
.wrapnewsrightbar2 { width: 250px; height:auto; float:right; background-color:#ffffff; }

#wrapperMain3 { width:auto; height: 350px; background-color:#ffffff; }
#wrapperMain3 p { font-family:open-sans; font-size:14px; color:#000000; font-weight:100; }
#wrapperMain3_subleft3 { width:auto; height: 200; background-color:#F6BE78; }
#wrapperMain3_subright3 { width:auto; height: 200; background-color:#F6BE23; }

#wrapnews3 { width: 1000px; height:800px; background-color:#ffffff; margin: 0 auto; }
.wrapperMain3news { width: 510px; height:750px; background-color:#ffffff; float:left; }
.wrapnewsrightbar3 { width: 400px; height:750px; float:right; background-color:#fff666; }
.wrapnewsrightbar3 p { font-family:open-sans; font-size:14px; color:#000000; font-weight:100; }

#wrapperMain4 { width:auto; height: 350px; background-color:#ffffff;}
#wrapperMain4 p { font-family:open-sans; font-size:14px; color:#000000; font-weight:100; }
#wrapperMain4_subleft4 { width:auto; height: 200; background-color:#F6BE55; }
#wrapperMain4_subright4 { width:auto; height: 200; background-color:#F6BE99; }

#wrapnews4 { width:1000px; height:810px; background-color:#FABE55; margin: 0 auto; }
.wrapperMain4news { width: 510px; height:810px; background-color:#F7BD44; float:left; }
.wrapnewsrightbar4 { width: 250px; height:auto; float:right; background-color:#F3AE54; }

#wrapperMain5 { width:auto; height: 200px; background-color:#ffffff; }
#wrapperMain5 p { font-family:open-sans; font-size:12px; color:#000000; font-weight:100; }
#wrapperMain5_subleft5 { width:auto; height: 200; background-color:#F6BE01; }
#wrapperMain5_subright5 { width:auto; height: 200; background-color:#F6BE25; }
#wrapperMain6 { width:auto; height: 300px; background-color:#F6BEB28; }

#wrap2 { width: 1000px; height: 300px; background-color:#ffffff; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top: 5px; }
#sub_left2 { width: 500px;height: 300px;float: left;background-color: #ffffff;margin-top: 5px;margin-left: 2px;color: #000000;font-family: open-sans;font-style: normal;font-weight: 300; text-decoration: none;
}
#sub_right2 {width:450px; height:280px; float:right; background-color:#ffffff; margin-top:5px; margin-right:2px; }
h3 { font-family: 'Open Sans'; font-size:12px; font-weight:100; color:#000000; }

#wrap3 { width: auto; height:80px; background-color:#ffffff; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top: 5px; }

#menu { width: 1000px; height: 50px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; }
#menu img { margin: 0 auto;  }

.nav { border:0px solid #ccc; border-width:0px 0; list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0; text-align:center;
}
.nav li { display:inline;}
.nav a { display:inline-block; padding:10px; font:open-sans; font-size: 20px; font-weight:300; color:#000000; text-decoration:none; }

 
#wrap4_slider1 { width:1000px; height: 250px; background-color:#fffccc; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top: 5px; }
#wrap4_slider1 cycle-slideshow img { margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; }

#wrap_main1 { width:1000px; height:250px; margin-left:auto; background-color:#ffffff; margin-right:auto; margin-top:5px;  }
#sub_left1 { width: 500px; height: 280px; float:left; background-color:#ffffff; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 2px; }
#sub_right1 { width:450px; height:280px; float:right; background-color:#ffffff; margin-top:5px; margin-right:2px; }
#wrap_main1 #sub_right1 a { padding-top:10px; border: none; display: block; margin: 0 auto; }

#wrapvideos { width: 850px; height: 1100px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 2px;  }

.wrapshows0 {width: 1000px; height: 1000px; background-color:#ffffff; margin: 0 auto; }

th,td {margin: 0;text-align: center;border-collapse: collapse;outline: 1px solid #e3e3e3;}

td { padding: 5px 10px;}

th{background: #666;color: white;padding: 5px 10px;}

td:hover { cursor: pointer; background: #666; color: white;}

#main1_sub_left { width:500px; height: 350px; float:left; background-color:#ffffff; margin-top: 15px; margin-left:5px; }
#main1_sidebar { width:400px; min-height: 600px; float:right; background-color:#ffffff; margin-top: 20px; }

#wrap_main2 { width: 500px; height: 300px; float:left; background-color:#ffffff; margin-top: 12px; margin-left:5px; }

#wrap_34 { width:1000px; height:300px; background-color:#ffffff; margin-bottom:  }
#wrap_main3 { width: 500px; height: 300px; float:left; background-color:#ffffff; margin-top: 10px; margin-left:5px; }
#wrap_main4 { width: 450px; height: 280px; float: right; background-color:#ffffff; }
#wrap_main4 a img { margin: 10px 0px 20px 0px; }


#wrap_main5 { width: 500px; height: 300px; float:left; background-color:#ffffff; margin-top: 5px; margin-left:5px; }

#social_media { width: auto; height: 100px; background-color:#C7C5C5;; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top: 20px; }
#social_media table { margin:0 auto; padding-top:15px; }

#footer {width:auto; height:50px; margin:auto; background-color:#888888; margin-top: 5px; }
#footer p { font-family: 'Open Sans'; font-size:12px; font-weight:100; color:#000000; padding: 20px 0px 0px 10px;  }
#footer p1 { font-family: open-sans; font-size:12px; font-weight:100; color:#000000; padding: 20px 0px 0px 10px; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Welcome to SoulTrain Radio</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="STRv1.css">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.center.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrap1">
<table width="500" border="0">
 <tr>
  <td class="first"><img src="titlesListenLive.png" width="200" height="80" alt=""/></td>
  <td class="second"></td>
  <td class="third"><audio controls autoplay>
    <source src="http://93.190.141.15:7003/live?type=.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio></td>
 </tr>
</table>
  
  </div><!--wrap1 -->


<div id="wrap2_wrapper">
<img src="STRBristol_Logo.jpg" width="1000" height="250" alt=""/></div><!--wrap2_wrapper -->



<div id="menu">
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="shows.html">DJs &#038; SHOWS</a></li>
  <li><a href="events.html">EVENTS</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.html">NEWS</a></li>
  <li><a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
  <li><a href="videos.html">VIDEOS</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="wrap4_slider1"> 
<div class="cycle-slideshow"
data-cycle-fx=scrollHorz
    data-cycle-timeout=8000
data-cycle-center-horz=true
    data-cycle-center-vert=true>
    <img src="slider3.jpg" width="1000">
</div><!--cycle-slideshow -->
</div><!--wrap4_slider1 -->

<div id="wrapperMain"> 
<hr> 

<div id="wrap_main1"> 
<div id="sub_left1"> <img src="easter-poster.jpg" width="450" height="280" alt=""/></div>
<div id="sub_right1"> <a href="https://yplanapp.com/bristol/funk-up-your-good-friday-46369/" data-yplan="widget" data-width="450px"></a></div> 
</div><!--wrap_main1 -->

<br>
<br>
<div id="wrap2">
 <hr>
<div id="sub_left2">  
<h2> SOULTRAIN HISTORY... </h2>
<p>History 
Quoted by massive attack as early influencers on the ‘ Bristol sound ‘ the origins of Soultrain can be traced back to the early 1970’s which a BBC radio 6 documentary reported Soultrain DJ importing funk 45's and creating an underground scene whilst everybody else was into pop or punk / heavy rock. Local author Chris Brown has penned a book " suited and booted " acknowledging brothers Steve & Adrian Ashby & Paul Alexander as movers and shakers back in the day!   
</p>

<p> <a href="about.html" title="More..." target="_blank">More...</a> </p>


 <hr> </div>

<div id="sub_right2"> <iframe width="450" height="260" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dcR1gwRRbQc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><h3>Soultrain at Motion Bristol.. <a href="videos.html" title="Videos" target="_blank">More...</a></h3> </div>
</div><!--wrap2 -->

<div  id="main1_sidebar"> <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/STRBristol" data-widget-id="697848027965480961">Tweets by @STRBristol</a> <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</div>

<br>


<div id="main1_sub_left" > <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p><p>"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. "</p></div>

<br>

<div id="wrap_main2"> <hr>  <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p> <hr></div>
<br>

<div id="wrap_34">
<div id="wrap_main3"> <hr> <p>"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"</p> <hr></div>

<div id="wrap_main4"> <a href="advertise.html"><img src="advertise_str.png" width="450" height="300" alt=""/></a></div>
</div><!--wrap_34 -->
<BR>
</div><!--wrapperMain -->

<div id="social_media">
<table width="1000" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col"><img src="tune_in.png" width="150" height="50" alt=""/></th>
      <th scope="col"><img src="facebook_icon.png" width="150" height="50" alt=""/></th>
      <th scope="col"><img src="instagram_icon.png" width="150" height="50" alt=""/></th>
      <th scope="col"><img src="mixcloud_icon.png" width="150" height="50" alt=""/></th>
      <th scope="col"><img src="twitter_icon.png" width="150" height="50" alt=""/></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div><!-- Social_media -->

<div id="footer">
<p>© 2016 SoulTrain Radio. All Rights Reserved.</p>
<p1>Created - Cr8tive M8di4 </p1> 
</div>


<script src="//yplanapp.com/affiliate/v1/widget.js"></script>
<script>
  YPlan.register({
    partnerId: 'a-partner-id',
    medium: 'backlink',
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are using a table for displaying simples images, use css instead, or juste disable cellspacing of the array

Answer (score 1):

Remove the outline

```
th, td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 1px solid #e3e3e3; // remove this line
    text-align: center;
}
```

Remove the background on hover

```
td:hover {
    background: #666 none repeat scroll 0 0; // remove this line
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the **background** and **white borders**:

```
th, td {
  background: transparent;
  outline: 0
}
```

To remove the background **(on hover)**:

```
th:hover, td:hover {
  background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet with the outline and hover color removed.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */


#wrap1 { width: 1000px; height: 100px; background-color:#F9C6C7; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top: 1px; }
#wrap1 table { width:1000px; }

.first { float:right; padding-top: 10px;}
.third { float:left; }

#wrap2_wrapper { width: 1000px; height: 250px; background-color:#000000; margin: 0 auto; }
#wrap2_wrapper img { padding-top:1px; border: none; max-height: 100%; margin: 0 auto;}


#wrapperMain { width: 1000px; min-height: 2000px; background-color:#ffffff; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top: ; padding-top: 5px; }
#wrapperMainvideos { width: 1000px; min-height: 1100px; background-color:#ffffff; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; }

#wrapperMain1 { width:1000px; height: 1000px; background-color:#ffffff; }
#wrapperMain2 { width:1000px; height: 250px; background-color:#ffffff; }
#wrapperMain2 p { font-family:open-sans; font-size:14px; color:#000000; font-weight:100; }
#wrapperMain2_subleft2 { width:auto; height: 200; background-color:#F6BE44; }
#wrapperMain2_subright2 { width:auto; height: 200; background-color:#F6BE22; }

#wrapnews2 #wrapnews3 {border-bottom: 3px solid #4588ba; margin-bottom:10px;}

#wrapnews2 { width:1000px; height:810px; background-color:#ffffff; margin: 0 auto;  }
.wrapperMain2news { width: 1000px; height:810px; background-color:#ffffff; margin: 0 auto; }
.wrapnewsrightbar2 { width: 250px; height:auto; float:right; background-color:#ffffff; }

#wrapperMain3 { width:auto; height: 350px; background-color:#ffffff; }
#wrapperMain3 p { font-family:open-sans; font-size:14px; color:#000000; font-weight:100; }
#wrapperMain3_subleft3 { width:auto; height: 200; background-color:#F6BE78; }
#wrapperMain3_subright3 { width:auto; height: 200; background-color:#F6BE23; }

#wrapnews3 { width: 1000px; height:800px; background-color:#ffffff; margin: 0 auto; }
.wrapperMain3news { width: 510px; height:750px; background-color:#ffffff; float:left; }
.wrapnewsrightbar3 { width: 400px; height:750px; float:right; background-color:#fff666; }
.wrapnewsrightbar3 p { font-family:open-sans; font-size:14px; color:#000000; font-weight:100; }

#wrapperMain4 { width:auto; height: 350px; background-color:#ffffff;}
#wrapperMain4 p { font-family:open-sans; font-size:14px; color:#000000; font-weight:100; }
#wrapperMain4_subleft4 { width:auto; height: 200; background-color:#F6BE55; }
#wrapperMain4_subright4 { width:auto; height: 200; background-color:#F6BE99; }

#wrapnews4 { width:1000px; height:810px; background-color:#FABE55; margin: 0 auto; }
.wrapperMain4news { width: 510px; height:810px; background-color:#F7BD44; float:left; }
.wrapnewsrightbar4 { width: 250px; height:auto; float:right; background-color:#F3AE54; }

#wrapperMain5 { width:auto; height: 200px; background-color:#ffffff; }
#wrapperMain5 p { font-family:open-sans; font-size:12px; color:#000000; font-weight:100; }
#wrapperMain5_subleft5 { width:auto; height: 200; background-color:#F6BE01; }
#wrapperMain5_subright5 { width:auto; height: 200; background-color:#F6BE25; }
#wrapperMain6 { width:auto; height: 300px; background-color:#F6BEB28; }

#wrap2 { width: 1000px; height: 300px; background-color:#ffffff; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top: 5px; }
#sub_left2 { width: 500px;height: 300px;float: left;background-color: #ffffff;margin-top: 5px;margin-left: 2px;color: #000000;font-family: open-sans;font-style: normal;font-weight: 300; text-decoration: none;
}
#sub_right2 {width:450px; height:280px; float:right; background-color:#ffffff; margin-top:5px; margin-right:2px; }
h3 { font-family: 'Open Sans'; font-size:12px; font-weight:100; color:#000000; }

#wrap3 { width: auto; height:80px; background-color:#ffffff; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top: 5px; }

#menu { width: 1000px; height: 50px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; }
#menu img { margin: 0 auto;  }

.nav { border:0px solid #ccc; border-width:0px 0; list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0; text-align:center;
}
.nav li { display:inline;}
.nav a { display:inline-block; padding:10px; font:open-sans; font-size: 20px; font-weight:300; color:#000000; text-decoration:none; }

 
#wrap4_slider1 { width:1000px; height: 250px; background-color:#fffccc; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top: 5px; }
#wrap4_slider1 cycle-slideshow img { margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; }

#wrap_main1 { width:1000px; height:250px; margin-left:auto; background-color:#ffffff; margin-right:auto; margin-top:5px;  }
#sub_left1 { width: 500px; height: 280px; float:left; background-color:#ffffff; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 2px; }
#sub_right1 { width:450px; height:280px; float:right; background-color:#ffffff; margin-top:5px; margin-right:2px; }
#wrap_main1 #sub_right1 a { padding-top:10px; border: none; display: block; margin: 0 auto; }

#wrapvideos { width: 850px; height: 1100px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 2px;  }

.wrapshows0 {width: 1000px; height: 1000px; background-color:#ffffff; margin: 0 auto; }

th,td {margin: 0;text-align: center;border-collapse: collapse;}

td { padding: 5px 10px;}

th{background: #666;color: white;padding: 5px 10px;}

#main1_sub_left { width:500px; height: 350px; float:left; background-color:#ffffff; margin-top: 15px; margin-left:5px; }
#main1_sidebar { width:400px; min-height: 600px; float:right; background-color:#ffffff; margin-top: 20px; }

#wrap_main2 { width: 500px; height: 300px; float:left; background-color:#ffffff; margin-top: 12px; margin-left:5px; }

#wrap_34 { width:1000px; height:300px; background-color:#ffffff; margin-bottom:  }
#wrap_main3 { width: 500px; height: 300px; float:left; background-color:#ffffff; margin-top: 10px; margin-left:5px; }
#wrap_main4 { width: 450px; height: 280px; float: right; background-color:#ffffff; }
#wrap_main4 a img { margin: 10px 0px 20px 0px; }


#wrap_main5 { width: 500px; height: 300px; float:left; background-color:#ffffff; margin-top: 5px; margin-left:5px; }

#social_media { width: auto; height: 100px; background-color:#C7C5C5;; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top: 20px; }
#social_media table { margin:0 auto; padding-top:15px; }

#footer {width:auto; height:50px; margin:auto; background-color:#888888; margin-top: 5px; }
#footer p { font-family: 'Open Sans'; font-size:12px; font-weight:100; color:#000000; padding: 20px 0px 0px 10px;  }
#footer p1 { font-family: open-sans; font-size:12px; font-weight:100; color:#000000; padding: 20px 0px 0px 10px; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Welcome to SoulTrain Radio</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="STRv1.css">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.center.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrap1">
<table width="500" border="0">
 <tr>
  <td class="first"><img src="titlesListenLive.png" width="200" height="80" alt=""/></td>
  <td class="second"></td>
  <td class="third"><audio controls autoplay>
    <source src="http://93.190.141.15:7003/live?type=.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio></td>
 </tr>
</table>
  
  </div><!--wrap1 -->


<div id="wrap2_wrapper">
<img src="STRBristol_Logo.jpg" width="1000" height="250" alt=""/></div><!--wrap2_wrapper -->



<div id="menu">
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="shows.html">DJs &#038; SHOWS</a></li>
  <li><a href="events.html">EVENTS</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.html">NEWS</a></li>
  <li><a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
  <li><a href="videos.html">VIDEOS</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="wrap4_slider1"> 
<div class="cycle-slideshow"
data-cycle-fx=scrollHorz
    data-cycle-timeout=8000
data-cycle-center-horz=true
    data-cycle-center-vert=true>
    <img src="slider3.jpg" width="1000">
</div><!--cycle-slideshow -->
</div><!--wrap4_slider1 -->

<div id="wrapperMain"> 
<hr> 

<div id="wrap_main1"> 
<div id="sub_left1"> <img src="easter-poster.jpg" width="450" height="280" alt=""/></div>
<div id="sub_right1"> <a href="https://yplanapp.com/bristol/funk-up-your-good-friday-46369/" data-yplan="widget" data-width="450px"></a></div> 
</div><!--wrap_main1 -->

<br>
<br>
<div id="wrap2">
 <hr>
<div id="sub_left2">  
<h2> SOULTRAIN HISTORY... </h2>
<p>History 
Quoted by massive attack as early influencers on the ‘ Bristol sound ‘ the origins of Soultrain can be traced back to the early 1970’s which a BBC radio 6 documentary reported Soultrain DJ importing funk 45's and creating an underground scene whilst everybody else was into pop or punk / heavy rock. Local author Chris Brown has penned a book " suited and booted " acknowledging brothers Steve & Adrian Ashby & Paul Alexander as movers and shakers back in the day!   
</p>

<p> <a href="about.html" title="More..." target="_blank">More...</a> </p>


 <hr> </div>

<div id="sub_right2"> <iframe width="450" height="260" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dcR1gwRRbQc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><h3>Soultrain at Motion Bristol.. <a href="videos.html" title="Videos" target="_blank">More...</a></h3> </div>
</div><!--wrap2 -->

<div  id="main1_sidebar"> <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/STRBristol" data-widget-id="697848027965480961">Tweets by @STRBristol</a> <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</div>

<br>


<div id="main1_sub_left" > <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p><p>"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. "</p></div>

<br>

<div id="wrap_main2"> <hr>  <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p> <hr></div>
<br>

<div id="wrap_34">
<div id="wrap_main3"> <hr> <p>"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"</p> <hr></div>

<div id="wrap_main4"> <a href="advertise.html"><img src="advertise_str.png" width="450" height="300" alt=""/></a></div>
</div><!--wrap_34 -->
<BR>
</div><!--wrapperMain -->

<div id="social_media">
<table width="1000" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col"><img src="tune_in.png" width="150" height="50" alt=""/></th>
      <th scope="col"><img src="facebook_icon.png" width="150" height="50" alt=""/></th>
      <th scope="col"><img src="instagram_icon.png" width="150" height="50" alt=""/></th>
      <th scope="col"><img src="mixbutt_icon.png" width="150" height="50" alt=""/></th>
      <th scope="col"><img src="twitter_icon.png" width="150" height="50" alt=""/></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div><!-- Social_media -->

<div id="footer">
<p>© 2016 SoulTrain Radio. All Rights Reserved.</p>
<p1>Created - Cr8tive M8di4 </p1> 
</div>


<script src="//yplanapp.com/affiliate/v1/widget.js"></script>
<script>
  YPlan.register({
    partnerId: 'a-partner-id',
    medium: 'backlink',
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for all your assistance.

Answer (score -1):

Add `th, td{outline-style: none;}` to your CSS.